# Pass Information to Middleware from Controller

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-middleware

I've set up a middleware in my asp.net core application to automatically wrap controller actions in a transaction.

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, MyDataContext dbContext)
{
    if (context.Request.Method == "GET")
    {
        await _next(context);
    }
    else
    {
        using (var transaction = await dbContext.Database.BeginTransactionAsync())
        {
            try
            {
                await _next(context);
                transaction.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                transaction.Rollback();
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However I have one controller method (possibly more in the future) that should not run in a transaction. What would be the best way to get that controller action to "opt-out" of the middleware functionality?

It would be nice to place a custom attribute like [NoTransaction] on a controller method. However I'm unable to determine if there's any way to resolve, from the Invoke() method of my middleware, exactly *which* controller action will be invoked (which would enable me to pull the attributes from that method and determine whether to create a transaction.) What would be the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is a custom Filter.

You could create a new class that derives from ActionFilterAttribute.
Then you can override the OnActionExecuting and OnActionExecuted methods to add your transaction handling.

You can then add the the filter via attribute to the methods where you would like to run them. `[CustomFilter]` in case you named your class "CustomFilterAttribute".

If you need more control over the lifetime of the filter class you can use the ActionFilter as ServiceFilter. It requires registering it as service and will also allow you to use dependency injection.
ServiceFilter Attributes look slightly different:

```
[ServiceFilter(typeof(CustomFilter))]
```

A good reference for this is:
https://damienbod.com/2015/09/15/asp-net-5-action-filters/

Comment: This sounds interesting but I'm not sure I understand the proposal - does this allow me to have system-wide transactions for controller actions by default, and then use the attribute to opt out?

Comment: My proposed solution would be better fitted with an opt-in approach and having the transaction handling inside the Filter code.

For opting-out have a look at the "Using the filter as a global filter" section in the provided link. You can basically apply a default filter to all Controllers.

You could then just add a boolean as parameter to specify if you want to create a transaction or not and manually add the attribute anywhere you want no transaction to be created.

Comment: the ActionFilter's methods are called at the beginning and end of your method so you need to make the transaction a member of the class. make sure that you call transaction.Dispose() ;

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out!

Comment: FelschR I haven't had a chance to try this out yet (the opt-out functionality isn't needed until a later product iteration) but I like your answer and I don't want to leave this question open. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question in your title, there is another way you can pass any object through to your middleware components: [HttpContext.Items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcontext.items?view=netframework-4.7.2)

It's a bit of a blunt instrument, but if you have no other option, it can work.

In the controller:

```
ControllerContext.HttpContext.Items["variable"] = "value";
```

In the middleware:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    if ((string)context.Items["variable"] == "value")
    {
        // do stuff
    }
    await next.Invoke();
});
```

Obviously it's best to be avoided since it bypasses type safety and there are usually other better methods in place to deal with this.